# AWS Beanstalk ebextensions on windows

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get my ebextensions config working to create a temp folder and give it permissions, but it isn't working.

```
commands:
  00mkdir:
    command: mkdir C:\tmp\
  01fix_perms:
    command: cacls C:\tmp /t /e /g Everyone:f
```

this is in 00_temp.config in .ebextensions. I'm using MS Visual Studio to upload to AWS Beanstalk. But we still don't get a temp folder.

Answer (score 2):

Use double backslashes. Such as in

```
commands: mkdir C:\\tmp\\
```

Same for the cacls command, of course. I have just done a test run with my EB configuration and it works. If for some reason this does not work for you, check the following:

- Make sure your .ebextensions*.config files are definitely in the zip file (some zip programs ignore dot-prefixed files by default)
- Make sure that you have SPACES in the configuration file for indentation (not tabs). To be sure, use something like TextPad.
- For other problems I had, I have found good information in `C:\cfn\log`
- I assume that you test the creation of the directory by connecting with MSTSC to the instance; if you only test it through your application, some other issues (permissions) may cause the problem.

Comment: I've tried this, but still no luck on the folder being created.

Comment: Check my updated response, worked on a testrun with my configuration.

Comment: I got it working, turns out VS wasn't uploading the config :/

Comment: Because you did not have the Copy To Output Directory set?