# Amazon EC2 IIS-8 User's Permission Write Access

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk deployment process through Visual Studio all is working well, except that when the application is deployed it does not have by default write permission; so I had to manually Remote Desktop the individual machine; and give it write permission through IIS site and under permissions.

How can I automate this process, since amazon servers adds on to load balancer using auto-scaling etc.?

Or If I change one, the other to follow will copy the exact same thing, which I had done manually?

I am little confused, first time deploying, please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use ebextensions config to set permissions on the directory after the instance spins up. Here is an example of someone creating a directory and setting the permissions on the new directory, you should be able to adapt to your circumstances:

[AWS Beanstalk ebextensions on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647061/aws-beanstalk-ebextensions-on-windows)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the link, can this be used for giving permission to specific user or group on Windows?

Comment: Yes, because the cacls program (or icacls) is a generic tool for setting permissions - you just need to specify what you want done with the command line parameters.

Comment: I tried that, it looks like the command ran successfully and I got the permission, but it is giving me the error "Error encountered during build of Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed" after success from command." from Elastic Beanstalk